# Calculate how many occurrences are needed to achieve average in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following numbers from a ticketing system:

```
Closed Tickets: 10
Transferred Tickets: 10
Total Tickets: 20
The current average is: Closed tickets/Total tickets = 10/20 = 0.5 = 50%
```

What I need to calculate is how many additional Closed tickets I need to achieve an average of 80% or greater.

So my calculation would be:

```
(Closed Tickets + x) / (Total tickets + x) = 0.8
(10 + x) / (20 + x) = 0.8
```

How can I achieve this in DAX so I get the X value calculated? Is there a special function for that? I have searched but unfortunately did not find anything.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Solve the equation for x and put formula in calculated column. That's it

Comment: Here is the calculation logic: =((Total Tickets/100)*80)-Closed Tickets

Comment: I get `x = (4 * Total Tickets) - (5 * Closed Tickets)` as the required logic.

Comment: @Jos Wolley. This seems to be correct. Thank you. May I ask how you got to the values 4 and 4? so I can adapt this function if I am looking for an other percentage?

Comment: @SergeInácio I just did some basic algebra: `(Closed Tickets + x) / (Total Tickets + x) = 0.8` can be rearranged to `(Closed Tickets + x) = (0.8 * Total Tickets) + (0.8 * x)`, which, bringing the *x*s all to one side, is `0.2 * x = (0.8 * Total Tickets) - Closed Tickets`, which gives `x = 5 * [(0.8 *  Total Tickets) - Closed Tickets]`, which gives is  `x = (4 * Total Tickets) - (5 * Closed Tickets)`.